# How to use custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I KNOW this is a repost, but I've been trying to get this to work for ages (hours) now and I really can't understand the existing answers.
All i want to know is: How can I edit this code so it works? I'm trying to populate both textviews from two different arrays.

Only the second adapter gets read and the first one's textview stays blank.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

```
        public void run () {                

            if (t.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
                adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listlook, R.id.txtl2, names);
                setListAdapter(adapter2);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listlook, R.id.txtl1, comments);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                return;
            } else {
                h.postDelayed(this, 1000);  
            }

        }}
    , 1000);    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Listview within Usercomments.xml

```
            <ListView
            android:id="@+android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" >
            </ListView>
```

listlook.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtl1"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtl2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtl1"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#5C002E"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

listlook is just the layout i use in the listview? Don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: An Adapter is attached to a ListView. I guess that your activity has only one ListView, since you can only have 1 adapter per ListView, you are replacing your first Adapter with the Seconds one. Which looks like only the second adapter is used. If you want to display both, you might want to add another ListView, or put both List into one, and retry.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I'm using a custom listview with two textviews, but I'm sort-of self-taught and can't undersatnd a word of the existing code about this type of thing. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I think the problem is, that you didnt understand the idea behind listView <-> adapter. A ListView doesnt have a specific count of TesxViews. Can you show the listLook layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're telling your list view that you want to use `adapter2`, and then telling it you want to use `adapter` - **it can only read data from one adapter at a time**.

If you want to display data from two lists, you could do something like this.

First, combine your two lists into a class, and build a `List<Post>` of these, instead of having two arrays:

```
public class Post {
    String mName, mComment;
    public Post(String name, String comment) {
        mName = name;
        mComment = comment;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return mComment;
    }

}
```

Then, write an adapter that knows how to display `Post` items:

```
public class PostAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private List<Post> mPosts;

    public TweetstreamAdapter(Activity activity, List<Post> posts) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mPosts = posts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPosts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Post getItem(int position) {
        return mPosts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Post post = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listlook, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtl1)).setText(post.getName());
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtl2)).setText(post.getComment());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Then in your activity, you set the adapter like this:

```
setListAdapter(new PostAdapter(this, posts));
```

where `posts` is a `List<Post>` of posts.

**Note**: <del>You'll need to ensure you have `TextView` entries in your `listlook` layout that have IDs that match those that the adapter is searching for. Update the code to match your IDs accordingly.</del> Updated to match your id's. This should just drop in, provided you construct a list of `Post` objects correctly.

Update 2: You could build a list like this, **assuming the two arrays (names/comments) are the same length**:

```
List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    posts.add(new Post(names[i], comments[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'm populating the lists with data from a PHPMySQL database. Very informative answer, but not very familiar with using different classes for one Activity, do I create the classes as is? Where will I put the method to call the JSON object?

Comment: You can create a list of `Post` objects using your existing string arrays using the code I've added above. Retrieving the data is a completely different issue; if you're not sure how to do that I'd recommend doing some more research and if you still can't figure it out then open a new question.

Comment: If you are reading your data from a SQL Database, you might want to have a look at CustomCursorAdapter

Comment: The list is populating and the server works. But like you said it's just using the second adapter. So I'll still call it in the activity, then just create the list using the second edit?

Comment: Yeah, create the list, then replace the 4 lines you have for creating & setting the adapter with just: `setListAdapter(new PostAdapter(this, posts));`

Answer (score 0):

You have two lines with `setListAdapter()`. The second overwrite the first. If you have two `ListViews` then do this:

```
listView1.setListAdapter(adapter2);
listView2.setListAdapter(adapter);
```